# Executing a command based on a Short-Time Fourier Transform Output

Tags: python, stft

I am currently calculating a [Short-Time Fourier Transform (STFT)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.stft.html) in Python using `scipy.signal.stft`.  I am producing the image of the STFT shown below in real-time, based on the data that I have streaming in.

I am looking to trigger an event warning when the frequencies detected are similar to those after the 50th time segment.  I want the event warning to neglect the events that you can see before the 30th time segment.

One idea that I have had are as follows:

- Calculate the length of the time segment where certain frequencies are present.  And if the time is less than a few time segments, then I should disregard them.  However, if the time segment at that frequency lasts longer than, let's say, 10 segments, then I should produce the event warning.

Any other ideas, or help is greatly appreciated!

The STFT is being called as follows, and I have my data streaming in from a sensor.
`f, t, Zxx = scipy.signal.stft(data['Z'], fs=250, nperseg = 50)`

The x-axis is the array of segment times.  The y-axis is the array of sample frequencies.

[image]